# getRequestDispatcher not redirecting anchor url?

Tags: jsp, servlets, modal-dialog, requestdispatcher

I have a getRequestDispatcher in my servlet that should redirect to an anchor url:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#stuff");
view.forward(request, response);
```

And in my jsp page (called index.jsp), I have a modal with the id "stuff".  Why is the servlet not redirecting it back to the modal??

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to access the jsp directly in the browser to see if it works? ie: http://yourhost/index.jsp#stuff

Comment: I guess that's the issue.  It doesn't access directly.  How can I make it so I can access it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how that works. The `RequestDispatcher` is not a browser that can interpret `HTML` ids.

When you do

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#stuff");
```

you are telling your servlet container to find a resource at the path `index.jsp#stuff`. See the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29). If that is not a valid resource path, then the method will return `null`.

None of this controls how your browser is going to center on some element.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp#stuff");
```